# How I can send a json to a view from the controller in laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to make a server laravel, the idea is that given an email address and a password, you can search elusuario in the database and if there's one answer me with json. My problem is I do not know if I'm doing well

My code:

**Model**

```
Class Usuario extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Usuario';
}
```

**UsuarioController**

```
class UsuarioController extends BaseController{

public function buscarUsuario($Correo, $Contraseña){
    $usuario = Usuario::find($Correo,$Contraseña)->toJson();

    return View::make('usuario.lista', array('usuario' => $usuario));
}

}
```

**lista.blade.php(view/usuario)**

```
{{$usuario}}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('usuario/{Correo}/{Contraseña}', array('uses' => 'UsuarioController@buscarUsuario'));
```

I also would like to know, how can I send values ​​ls URL to see if the JSON works well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to return a json as response:

```
class UsuarioController extends BaseController {

    public function buscarUsuario($Correo, $Contraseña)
    {
        $usuario = Usuario::find($Correo,$Contraseña);

        return Response::json(array('usuario' => $usuario));
    }

}
```

If you follow the url using your browser:

```
http://localhost/marsur-servidor/usuario/user@domain.com/mypassword12345
```

If, of course, your urls start with

```
http://localhost/marsur-servidor/
```

And you should see:

```
{
    usuario: {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if Laravel and PHP will play nice with accents too, so you may have to change (in all of your code)

```
Contraseña
```

To

```
Contrasena
```

Comment: How I can know if it works?, should send data into URL to test?

Comment: If you are opening it in your browser, you should see a json.

Comment: Edited to provide info about user and password.

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. Just added an observation about `ñ` in my answer.

Comment: mu route is fine?? 

Route::get('usuario/{Correo}/{Contrasena}', array('uses' => 'UsuarioController@buscarUsuario'));

Comment: I can't see the json on the browser :S

Comment: What do you see? Errors? Take a look at the page source code, sometimes the browser just don't show it directly.

Comment: I only see a blank page when I try. My code "Blade" is as follows **{{$response}}**

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example of *responding* with JSON.  You don't really need a view to send JSON, you just need a response:

```
public function buscarUsuario($Correo, $Contraseña) {
    $usuario = Usuario::find($Correo,$Contraseña)->toJson();
    $array = [ 'field1' => $usario->field1, 'field2' => $usario->field2 ];
    $statusCode = 200;
    $response = Response::json($array, $statusCode);
    return $response;
}
```

You can, however, leverage [some packages out there](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal) that will let you transform your JSON whenever it is requested.  [This](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/12/php-apis-fractal-of-good-design) is also a great article by Phil Sturgeon that talks about transformers and how they can help you, and has examples on using the package I linked to.

Comment: How I can know if it works?, should send data into URL to test?

Comment: Use REST client and send requests to your app.  Here's a chrome extension that works pretty good: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Comment: How I can get the response in the view?

Comment: There is no 'view'.  You're simply returning a JSON `Response`.  If you're trying to get to this json data from another view, then you need to issue an AJAX request to this route and then receive the JSON through javascript.

Comment: any tutorial of that? :D

Comment: doing ajax calls? Sure are.. this one uses jquery: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289

Comment: If you return the JSON response, you will show the json. Are you saying you want to display the textual representation of the JSON from within a normal blade template?

Comment: So I'm understanding your comment is that what I'm doing is right, the method return me but I can not see the JSON. No such call method "buscarUsuario" from the route or blade to show JSON. I think the blade is wrong because the JSON isn't printing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a JSON output, you shouldn't use View, but the special [JSON Response](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses). Otherwise the headers will not be json headers.
I am not entirely sure what your question is, but I hope this link helps you out.

```
<?php
public function buscarUsuario($Correo, $Contraseña){
    $usuario = Usuario::find($Correo,$Contraseña)->toJson();
    return Response::json($usario);
}
```

Comment: How I can know if it works?, should send data into URL to test?

Answer (score 0):

Returning the model directly from the controller will convert it to JSON, and send it as a JSON response:

```
public function buscarUsuario($Correo, $Contraseña)
{
    $user = Usuario::whereEmail($Correo)->first();

    if ( $user && Hash::check($Contraseña, $user->password) )
    {
            return $user;
    }
}
```

This assumes that your database columns are name `email` & `password` respectively. If they're different, switch them out.

Also, I'm assuming that the passwords in your database are hashed. If they're not (why???), just add the password as another `where` query:

```
public function buscarUsuario($Correo, $Contraseña)
{
    return Usuario::whereEmail($Correo)->wherePassword($Contraseña)->first();
}
```